# Centering child element that has siblings in parent div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-grid

I'm attempting to have a grandparent that has multiple parent divs. Some of the parent divs have 3 elements and others only have 1. I need the 2nd element of a parent div to always align in the middle (and also aligning with the single element in the 1 element div type). The first and 3rd elements in the 3 element div type need to be touching the 2nd element, and only move towards the edges if their content grows. How do I achieve this with CSS? Most solutions that I've found online involve using margins or absolute positioning, but that screws up the relationship between the 2nd element and the 1st/3rd elements that need to be touching the 2nd element.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="left-side">First Text!</span>
    <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
    <span class="right-side">Other Text!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: What alignment should look like]

Notice that the large yellow element in the middle is centered perfectly in the middle, and the left and right elements are touching the middle element. The div with only one element still has that one element centered perfectly.
red is grandparent
blue is parent
yellow is child spans

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean; can you share a picture of what you expect?

Comment: How does this relate to Bootstrap? you don't seem to be using any Bootstrap classes. Centered vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @Zim I included bootstrap because if there was a solution using bootstrap I would be able to use it.

Comment: @IvanS95 finished uploading the picture

Comment: Is there other CSS that is setting the widths and height of the boxes?

Comment: @Zim kind of. The width of the grandparent is actually a bootstrap column, so theoretically the grandparent could have variable width

Comment: wow! Thank you for the responses everyone. I chose the simplest answer that got the job done as the correct answer, but many of these answers we also great. Anybody coming to this question later should examine all of these depending on their scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use grid to separate .parent into 3 sections, left and right have equal length and text-align: right on left side

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.left-side {
  text-align: right;
}

.must-be-centered { 
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="left-side">First Text!</span>
    <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
    <span class="right-side">Other Text!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution was the simplest one that got the job done for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox to horizontally center-align your columns. Each `.child` class will interact with sibling elements that have an immediate parent property with `display: flex`

```css
.grandparent {
  background-color: #18bbf0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
.parent { 
  display: flex; /* control child behavior */
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal centering */
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
}
.child {
  background-color: #18bbf0;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">First Text!</div>
    <div class="child">SOME TEXT!</div>
    <div class="child">Other Text!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">SOME TEXT!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice answer except that it assumes that the 3 child divs will take up 100% of the width, which isn't true for me

Comment: My answer was submitted before the graphic was added to the question. I'll remove the 100% total value.

Answer (score 1):

Something to get you started.

```css
#parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
  align-items: center;
}

.row > div {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 150px;
}

.row > div:only-child,
.row > div:nth-child(even) {
  flex: 0 0 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a great solution aside from the fact that I don't know how wide my spans are going to be (I should have mentioned that previously) so I can't hard code pixel values into flex

Comment: You can use any unit, or there might be a grid solution here too.

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap classes it would work like this (no extra CSS)...

```
<div class="grandparent min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="left-side">First Text!</span>
    <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
    <span class="right-side">Other Text!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/mOxENzsdjS

Comment: This solution vertically centered my spans which I didn't want, and also didn't work to align the "must-be-centered" spans that I needed. However, I feel like I learned tons about bootstrap just looking at the classes you chose to use.

Comment: please post a realistic example of your code. it's hard to understand what you already have.. everything looks vertically centered in the image posted

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox makes this kind of layout very easy. On the `.must-be-centered` divs check out the combination of the `flex: 1 0 auto;` rule which allows it to grow, and the `max-width` to regulate the size how you like.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}
.parent {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.parent > span {
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.must-be-centered {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="left-side">First Text!</span>
    <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
    <span class="right-side">Other Text!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. The only issue is that it uses hard coded margins/padding to push the "First Text!" and "Other Text" to the middle next to "SOME TEXT!" when in reality my parent divs are much wider than the child spans, so when I tried this the outside spans slid to the edges of the parent container

Answer (score 1):

I just write basic code snippet for all your scenarios, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.grandparent {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

span {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

.must-be-centered {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <span class="left-side">First Text!</span>
    <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
    <span class="right-side">Other Text!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
     <span class="must-be-centered">SOME TEXT!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using display:flex. Try setting the following on your parent element:

```
.parent {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are speaking about vertical alignment, rather than horizontal alignment. This is easily done with flex:

```
.grandparent{
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
} 
.parent{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```